# How highlight part of the text React

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, reactjs, replace

have a search query and result title. I want to highlight a words in title which corresponds search query

```
  function lightString(string, query) {
      return string.split(" ").map(item => item.toUpperCase() === query.toUpperCase() ? `<span className='some-class'>${item}<span/>` : item).join(" ");
  }
  let result = lightString(product.title, searchWords[0])

  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: result}} />
```

But in result I have unwanted nestings: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkN9O.png)

Maybe you have any ideas how realise it?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a small typo in your `lightString` method.

You have
    `<span className='some-class'>${item}<span/>`

Instead try
    `<span class='some-class'>${item}</span>`

Notice the position of the `/` in the ending `<span />` tag. Does this solve the issue?

**Side note:**

`className` is only used with `JSX`. In your example, you are injecting innerHTML and not using `JSX`. In that instance, use `class` instead. Notice in your image how `className` is used in the `attribute` rather than `class`.